# display in JTable part of a collection

Tags: java, swing, collections, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have created a JTable using AbstractTableModel in which I added a collection of objects (ArrayList).
I want to be able to search through the objects and return in the same JTable only the ones that meet a conditions (for example the names starts with "St"). Theoretically, how can I do that? Do I have to make new ArrayLists for every condition, and store these searched (and returned) objects there? Is there a better/simpler way? Thanks

Comment: yes is possible, nothing special, read 1. [Oracle tutorial How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), 2. [Oracle tutorial How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), 3. [Oracle tutorial How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: you need to showing some effort, e.g. search  [in post by @MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+[jtable]+abstracttablemodel), hes loves JTable + AbstractTableModel + util.List

Comment: thanks mKorbel for the tutorials !

Comment: glad if help you :-), btw in tutorial is exactly described everything that you can find out in posts by MadProgrammer, there nothing missing, I'm suggest to ask an questions, but probably I forgot to define that a new questions that meets with our standards here, much luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the thing, 
if you are looking for syntaxic filtering this functionality already exists in java as TableRowSorter which can be combined with row filter to set the subList and show it.

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), you can access a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) in your implementation of [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). As shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), you can sort and filter the results without modifying the original data structure. A complete example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513).