# Java swing toggle button to filter jtable rows

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, rowfilter

I have a `JTable`, it contains a custom `AbstractTableModel` that return an object when `getValueAt` is called. And of course I have a custom `TableCellRenderer` that is capable of getting/constructing the text from the object so that it can be displayed.

However now I would like to write a filter. Filter will be a simple toggle button. When it is turned on I would like the filter to be applied and when it is turned off I would like filter to be removed.

I have two problems due to that.

First one is that I have absolutely no idea how to write a filter when you have to filter by object rather than a primitive.

Second is I have no idea how to attached the said filter to the toggle button to be able to turn it on and off.

I am sorry if this is a retarded question but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting was the most useless documentation I saw since explanation was not in depth.

Thanks to anyone for their help.

EDIT:
The object contains multiple fields, but I am interested in two filter toggles specifically. One returns a `boolean` value when I say `isSuper`, and the second return a `string` when I call `getName`. If first toggle is turned on it should show all entries that return true on `isSuper`, and the second toggle should show all entries where name is compromised of two words (space is present) when I call `getName`.

Comment: What does the object you are trying to filter look like? On what property are you trying to filter on?

Comment: @MadProgrammer just updated the question with Edit :) I just want two toggles that is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) spell it out quite well...

With such little information to go on, the best you can hope for is an overview...

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> trs = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>();
table.setRowSorter(trs);

// Create the row filder...
trs.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {

    @Override
    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        boolean include = false;
        // Returns the value for the specific column...
        CustomObject value = (CustomObject)entry.getValue(filterColumn);
        if (filterBySuper) {
            include = value.isSuper();
        } else {
            include = value.getName().startsWith(fistPart) && value.getName().endWith(lastPart);
        }
        return include;
    }
});
```

When you want to update the filter, you simply need to call...

```
trs.sort();
```

Comment: My biggest problem was entry. I had no idea that it represents the object from the given row. Wow thank you so much :) This is amazing help

Comment: You should make use of both the tutorials and Java Docs.  I also employee simply test projects to see what is being passed so I can quantify the information into a contextual state - but I'm stupid like that ;)

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854854/jtable-rowfilter-and-rowfilter-entry)

Answer (score 3):

> First one is that I have absolutely no idea how to write a filter when you have to filter by object rather than a primitive.

Did you read the `RowFilter` API? It shows an example of how to create a custom filter based on a custom Object.

> Second is I have no idea how to attached the said filter to the toggle button to be able to turn it on and off.

Did you read the tutorial and try running the demo? The tutorial uses a DocumentFilter to change the filter dynamically every time the user changes the text in the text field. So the tutorial shows you how to dynamically changes the filter based on user input. You can modify the code to change the filter every time the toggle button is pressed.

> it contains a custom AbstractTableModel that return an object when getValueAt is called. And of course I have a custom TableCellRenderer that is capable of getting/constructing the text from the object so that it can be displayed.

Unrelated to my answer, but I don't really understand that statement. Are you saying every cell in the model returns a differently object, or does every cell return the same object but you just display a different property of the object for column1, column2, column3 etc? Either way it sounds like a weird design. We can probably suggest something better. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.