# JTable filter using multiple Jcheckboxes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, rowfilter

Question again about my Jtable ! I filter the results with JCheckBoxes ! When I check one checkbox the results are ok , but when I check two or more the results appear and follow the filter of the last JCheckBox rather than the filter of all checked JCheckBoxes . It's important to say that all checkboxes refered to one column of the table and are outside the table and used only for filtering the results in it.

My filter function is this

```
private void newFilter(String age){
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel,Object> rf = null;
    try{
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("20");
        }catch(java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e){
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

EDIT :  In the Table there are only the results , that should appear ! The ckeckboxes are outside the Jtable and are used only for filters , for example if I check the checkbox 20 in the table will appear only people with age 20 , but if I check age 20 and age 40 in the table will appear only the people with age of 40 and also with age 20 !

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513) or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17856131/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod None of them ! In the Table there are only the results , that should appear ! The ckeckboxes are outside the Jtable and are used only for filters , for example if I check the checkbox 20 in the table will appear only people with age 20 , but if I check age 20 and age 40 in the table will appear only the people with age of 40 and also with age 20 !

Comment: Pleas update your question to include this clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> The ckeckboxes are outside the `JTable` and are used only for filters…

You can combine and apply `JTable` row filters as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the functionality, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). Let the `Action` update the model, and the listening view will update itself in response.

Addendum: As a concrete example, change the `JButton` in the [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856131/230513) to a `JCheckBox`.

```
frame.add(new JCheckBox(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter")…
```

[image]

Comment: I have seen Java Tutorial but I didn't finf a solution :S

Comment: Also you provide me solutions about something else , I think ! can't come across to anything !

Comment: I think that I'm not clear ... I can Filter the table with one checkbox , the problem is when I try to filter it with two or more checkboxes ! I can't get your example if you can transform my given code to do what I'm saying I would be grateful ! Otherwise provide me other more easy example !

Comment: Instead of `RowFilter.andFilter()`, try `RowFilter.orFilter()`; more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_%28mathematics%29). For more detailed guidance, please edit your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in concern the last comment of @trashgod I came accross and changed my filter like this and now it works perfectly  :

```
private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<Object, Object> rf = null;
    List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(
            2);
        if (c20.isSelected()) {
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("20"));
        }
        if (c40.isSelected()) {
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("40"));
        }

    try {
        rf = RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```