# RowFilter using jcheckboxes and jtextfield in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I need help in making the RowFilter work. I'm trying to filter the 3rd column using the checkboxes below. It works fine when I click one of them but it doesn't work when multiple checkboxes are selected.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Full explanation would also help very much. Thanks in advance!

```
private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    java.util.List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> rfs = 
            new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);

    try {

        //Filter "Full Name" using TextField
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + textField.getText(), 0)); 

        /*  Filter "Employee Type" using CheckBoxes
         *  ex. If both chckbxAdmin and chckbxEmployee is checked, 
         *  Jtable will filter accordingly
         */
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + sfAdmin, 2));
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + sfEmployee, 2));
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + sfStaff, 2));

    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RowFilter<Object,Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

    sorter.setRowFilter(af);

}
```

Comment: A complete example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513).

Comment: Thanks, let me study the link you provided @trashgod

Comment: for regexFilter("(?i)" you can to use String value "true/false" for Boolean value stored in XxxTableModel, valid only for single argument to RowFilter