# Can I use RowFilter with a JTable to filter greater than or less than a column with type double?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double, rowfilter

I have a `JTable` with some data and the columns are as follows:

- Market - String
- Currency - String
- Volume - Double
- High - Double
- Low - Double

I have a text field for each and when you click a button it should filter the table.
I have it working with the Market and Currency Strings using:

```
RowFilter.regexFilter(txtMarket.getText(), 0);
RowFilter.regexFilter(txtCurrency.getText(), 1);
```

I want to use something similar to filter a greater than or less than for volume, high and low. Is this possible or should I try something else?

Sorry this is my first time asking a question I apologize for any missing information or formatting issues.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854854/jtable-rowfilter-and-rowfilter-entry), rest is in APIs

Comment: I looked at this but I find it very confusing and hard to read. I am fairly new to java and have never used jTables prior to this. I am specifically interested in finding out how to filter doubles in my JTable using RowFilter. Perhaps someone is able to break down how rowfilter deals with doubles?

Comment: @user3458837 "how rowfilter deals with doubles" they are unrelated. Fundamentally, you don't have to worry about if you are using doubles or a String or anything else. You just need to learn about how RowFilters work, how the `include` method works, what information you get in the `Entry` argument. And then you just do whatever you want to do. Whether it's double or string or integers, it makes no difference you just need to have a good picture of how the system work as a whole and make a good design. The details don't alter that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find info on greater than rowfilters https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html
This example shows you how you do it with integers.

Example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class example extends JPanel {
    private String[] columnNames = { "Volume"
    };

    private Object[][] data = { {new Integer(5)},
            {new Integer(1)},
            {new Integer(2)},
            {new Integer(3)},
            {new Integer(5)},
            {new Integer(5)},
            {new Integer(7)} };

    private DefaultTableModel myModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    private JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(myModel);
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    private JTextField filterText;



    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> GreaterThan = new RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer>() {
        public boolean include(Entry<? extends DefaultTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            myModel = entry.getModel();

            //0 is the first column
            if ((int) table.getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 0) > Integer.parseInt(filterText.getText())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> LessThan = new RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer>() {
        public boolean include(Entry<? extends DefaultTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            myModel = entry.getModel();

            //0 is the first column
            if ((int) table.getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 0) < Integer.parseInt(filterText.getText())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    public example() {
        filterText = new JTextField();
        button = new JButton("Click to sort Greater Than");
        button2 = new JButton("Click to sort Less Than");
        add(button);
        add(button2);
        add(scrollPane);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sorter.setRowFilter(GreaterThan);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sorter.setRowFilter(LessThan);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have it working with the Market and Currency Strings using:

Then check out the `RowFilter` API:

1. You can use the `RowFilter.numberFilter(...)` method to create two filters, one for "greater than" and one for "less than".
2. Then you can use the two filters from above and use the `RowFilter.and(...)` method to create the filter that you can use on your table.