# Using RowFilter with ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have tried my best to look at all docs and javadoc for the RowFilter. I am using an array list of objects and I have a AbstractTableModel for my JTable. I want to filter the JTable to only show the object(s) date property where it is after a certain date.

Is the AbstractTableModel used as the argument to the includes method? This is the example from the documentation.

```
   RowFilter<PersonModel,Integer> ageFilter = new RowFilter<PersonModel,Integer>() {
    public boolean include(Entry<? extends PersonModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
     PersonModel personModel = entry.getModel();
     Person person = personModel.getPerson(entry.getIdentifier());
     if (person.getAge() > 20) {
       // Returning true indicates this row should be shown.
       return true;
     }
       // Age is <= 20, don't show it.
       return false;
     }
 };
```

Is it possible to get an explanation of this includes method and some way of adapting it to my situation. I understand how to compare dates, but how does the method access the row and object in my JTable?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it's really very simply...once you've done it few times ;)

```
RowFilter<PersonModel, Integer> ageFilter = new RowFilter<PersonModel, Integer>() {
```

Obviously defines the constraints of the `RowFilter`, basically, it defines the "row model" (`PersonModel`) and the method of referencing the each row (`Integer`)

Basically, it says, "I have a `TableModel` which can be accessed via a `Integer` value"...

```
public boolean include(Entry<? extends PersonModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
```

Is the only `abstract` method that needs to be implemented ;)

```
PersonModel personModel = entry.getModel();
```

Gets the model from the `entry`

```
Person person = personModel.getPerson(entry.getIdentifier());
```

Basically, this gets the `Person` from the model using the row index as specified by `entry.getIdentifier()`

```
if (person.getAge() > 20) {
    // Returning true indicates this row should be shown.
    return true;
}
// Age is <= 20, don't show it.
return false;
```

Okay, that's pretty basic ;)...

Now, without any more information to go about your specific implementation, this is a REALLY basic example of what you "might" be able to do...

To make life easier, I simply wrapped it all up in a simple `class`, basically, when needed, you would create a new instance, passing the `Date` value to it and then setting the table's `RowSorter` filter with it...

```
public class DateRowFilter exetends RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
    private Date date;

    public DateRowFilter(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public boolean include(Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        boolean include = false;
        TableModel model = entry.getModel();
        int row = entry.getIdentifier();
        for (int col = 0; col < model.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            Object value = model.getValueAt(row, col);
            // Make decisions here
            // You'll probably want to use Date#isBefore or Date#isAfter
            // depending on which side you are comparing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A related example using `RowFilter.dateFilter` predicates is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Stop making life easy for this people ;)

Comment: The only half decent explanation I could find anywhere on how RowFilter works. Not one of the better Swing APIs....

Comment: @awmross It's meant to be able to do much more the filter tables, it "should" be capable of been added to something like a `JList` or even a `JTree`, to that end, it becomes a little complex.  Once you spend some time with it, it's not so bad, but it does have a high learning curve ;)