# How to order records by the date in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is my GUI. I basically want the records in the JTable to be in ascending order of date.

[image]

Can you please give an idea how to do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  *"I didn't add here my table record loading code because it is not relevant."*  Hard code some data for the example.

Comment: [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thank you modified it..

Comment: @trashgod actually there are other records also adding to this table. So I juts can't sort whole column. I need some specific condition like name.equals(listNLB.getSelectedValue().toString()). Because there going to be some records not matching for this condition.

Comment: You can combine predicates, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513).

Comment: *"thank you modified it.."*  I'll thank you to follow the links I offer and read them carefully.  There is still no MCVE/SSCCE above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see this example, I think it may help you
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SampleSortingTableModel.htm

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively this works as well:

> JTable.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(**index**);

**index** refers to the index of the column you want to arrange the records as of.