# Combining an andFilter with a orFIlter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have the following code for a rowfilter called newFilter

```
private void newFilter()
{
    RowFilter rfb = null;
    try //try catch block
    {
        List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filtersb = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(3);
        filtersb.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterAthID.getText(), 0));
        filtersb.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 1));
        filtersb.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterDate.getText(), 2));
        rfb = RowFilter.andFilter(filtersb);

        if(Blank.isShowing()==true)
        {
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 1));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 2));
            rfb = RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
        }

    } 
    catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e)
    {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rfb);
}
```

I attempted to combine the two filters so that when `Blank` was showing it would use the andFilter as well as the orFilter. However this did not work since rfb can only have one filter attached to it at a time. This leads me to the question, how would I combine the two row filters so that when `Blank` is showing the system uses the `filterAthID` to search column 0 **and** `filterForeName` to search column 1 **or** 2?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388366/merging-two-row-filters-for-a-jtable

Comment: @camickr If you are referring to your answer are you saying I can put a orFilter inside a andFilter?

Comment: @camickr because if i put an and filter on filterForeName for column 1 and 2 then it would require me to have the result I was searching for in both those columns however an orFilter there allows me to have it in only one or the other. But i also need the andFilter for searching with the filterAthID

Comment: I'm saying that posting answered your question on `how to merge filters` so the question should be marked as answered. Then using the concept from that question you should be able to solve this question. Create a filter that represents the AND condition. Create a filter that represent the OR condition. Then create a 3rd filter using the OR filter. I don't understand your exact requirement and since you didn't post a `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem I can't give specifics.

Comment: @camickr Thank you. I was unaware that I was able to call filters into a new filter

Comment: `I was unaware that I was able to call filters into a new filter` a RowFilter is a RowFilter. This is the whole concept of using polymorphism in Java.