# Java regexFilter combine andFilter with orFilter both being lists

Tags: java, excel, sorting, filter

I am trying to replicate excel filters in Java.

However, I can't get combined filters (multiple filter on more than one column in the same time) to work. I need to have an orFilter among filtered values of the same column (eg. among 205,76%, 2045,53%, 324,87%), while I need to join the orFilters with an andFilter among filtered columns (eg. among Qt di per... andFilter Coeff. di... columns).

Each filtering value (ticked values in the small filter table) is stored in a List<RowFilter<TableModel,Object>> in order to show only perfectly matching strings.

I saw this post [Merging two row filters for a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388366/merging-two-row-filters-for-a-jtable) regarding this topic, but this only merge two single filters, while I need to merge two lists of filters with the and condition while preserving the or condition among column values.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to answer this without seeing your attempted code.  Also, you appear to be filtering a column that contains percentages.  Are the values in the TableModel for that column Strings, or Doubles, or some other Number subclass?

Comment: Hi, values for this column are strings. I sorted it out by using the include method of Rowfilter object type which I was unaware of.