# JTable filtering by an exact match to a String

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I want to filter a `JTable` exactly by a string. My filter is like this:

```
Pattern.quote(textfield.getText());
```

But, when I filter on "G" I get also all lines of the `JTable` with the entry "KG". I just want the rows with the entry "G". I looked at [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), but I still don't see how.

Comment: I already know this site, just tell me how to compare the entries in the table with full matching with the filterText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example: [RowFilter#regexFilter(...) (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter-java.lang.String-int...-)

> The returned filter uses Matcher.find() to test for inclusion. To test for exact matches use the characters '^' and '$' to match the beginning and end of the string respectively. For example, "^foo$" includes only rows whose string is exactly "foo" and not, for example, "food". See Pattern for a complete description of the supported regular-expression constructs.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JTableFilterDemo2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"Item"};
    Object[][] data = {{"G"}, {"KG"}, {"XG"}, {"Y"}, {"Z"}, {"*G"}};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("G");

    JButton button = new JButton("Toggle filter");
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
      if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
      } else {
        String text = Pattern.quote(textField.getText());
        String regex = String.format("^%s$", text);
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex));
      }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    p.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JTableFilterDemo2().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), use a [`RowFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) to "to filter out entries from the model so that they are not shown in the view." To match "G" exactly in column zero, your filter might look like this:

```
final RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        return "G".equals(entry.getStringValue(0));
    }
};
```

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856131/230513), pressing the button in the example below toggles the filter.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/** https://stackoverflow.com/a/37114447/230513 */
public class JTableFilterDemo {

    private static TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    private Object[][] data = {{"G"}, {"KG"}, {"XG"}, {"Y"}, {"Z"}};
    private String columnNames[] = {"Item"};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return String.class;
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public JTableFilterDemo() {
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        final RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
                return "G".equals(entry.getStringValue(0));
            }
        };
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Filtering Table");
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTableFilterDemo jtfd = new JTableFilterDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```