# JTable custom RowFilter?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

RowFilter examples only do text comparison, but how does one filter rows that are linked to particular properties ?

my datamodel class

```
class MyDataModel
{
    private ArrayList<MyFile> data; // for the rows data
```

...

```
class Myfile
{
   private boolean error; // file name issues
   private boolean ignored; // file ignored for process
   private boolean exception; // file processed no matter other conditions
...
```

so how do I filter the rows where the MyFile has some property to true
(or even more complex tests on these fields)

thanks

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17856131/714968) answer by @trashgod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by text comparision? Have you added your filter and overridden include method?

```
boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends M,? extends I> entry)
```

The API document here [RowFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) itself explains how you can filter based on integer/number or based on any property type

Comment: indeed, strange the example I found only talked about regexfilter andfilter, orfilter...

Answer (score 0):

```
    RowFilter<Object,Object> filter = new RowFilter<Object,Object>() 
    {
       public boolean include(Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry) 
       {
           int rowID=(Integer)entry.getIdentifier();
           FilesTableModel data=(FilesTableModel) entry.getModel();
           return data.isVisible(rowID);
       }
    };
    TableRowSorter<FilesTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<FilesTableModel>(data);
    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```