# JTable with RowSorter changes selection upon filter change

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

This is a complicated problem, and unfortunately a small SSCCE would not be possible.  Therefore I have a long SCCE that demonstrates the problem.  The simplified sample program uses a simplified data source - Time Zones.  To use it, select a Time Zone in the table, then change the filter with the buttons at the top.  Notice the text at the bottom changing to show the application selection. **The undesired behavior is that when shifting to a filter that does not include the selected value, the selected value in the model is cleared.**  Surprisingly, when the selection is filtered out, the value is updated to being not set; but when filtered back in, the application selection is returned.

The Swing-based application's design is a Model-ViewModel-View, the Model is supposed to be the authoritative source for the application's data, including what the current selection is.  The Model can have multiple ViewModel-Views displaying the data in the Model.  This current selection may be reflected in multiple views.  The user should be able to change the selection from any View.  The selection may or may not be visible in all Views if it doesn't apply to some Views (a real-world example might be a View that shows vehicle maintenance may not show trips being taken by the vehicle).

The sample program has a `JLabel` as a simplified View-only of the application's selection, which displays at the bottom of the app the selection in the model.

The other more relevant View is a `JTable` that shows one Time Zone (as a String) per row.  It has a custom `ListSelectionModel` as the ViewModel that forwards change requests to the application Model, and listens to changes from the application Model and applies them to the selection by calling methods on super.  This works as expected, at least until filtering is applied.

The process of filtering is done mostly within the `JTable` and its inner classes, such as `JTable$SortManager`.  It seems to remember and clear the selection, perform the sort and filter, and then restore the selection or nothing if the selected value is not in the newly filtered set.

Unfortunately, in the `ListSelectionModel`, these clearing and selecting operations are changing the underlying selection in the application Model.  In my actual application, the selection loads a lot more information to display about the selection, and is a relatively expensive operation, so spurious changes to this value should be avoided.

So the question is this:  **Is there a way to prevent the application Model's selection from being changed when changing the table filter?**  I imagine the solution would fall under one of these categories:

- There may be some way of detecting within the `ListSelectionModel` when the filter/sort is in progress, and not update the application model while that is happening
- There may be something that can be overridden somewhere to change the undesired behavior

Here is the sample code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TableProblem
    extends JFrame
{
    public static final class ApplicationModel
    {
        String[] data = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        public String[] getData() { return data; }

        private String modelSelection;
        public String getModelSelection() { return modelSelection; }
        public void setModelSelection(String value) { modelSelection = value; fireModelSelectionChange(); }

        private void fireModelSelectionChange()
        { selectionListeners.forEach(l -> l.modelSelectionChanged(modelSelection, findModelIndex(modelSelection))); }

        private int findModelIndex(String value)
        {
            if (value != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (value.equals(data[i]))
                        return i;
            return -1;
        }
        private List<ApplicationModelSelectionListener> selectionListeners = new ArrayList<>();
        public void addSelectionListener(ApplicationModelSelectionListener l) { selectionListeners.add(l); }
    }

    public interface ApplicationModelSelectionListener
    {
        void modelSelectionChanged(String selection, int selectedModelIndex);
    }

    /** This class acts as the selection ViewModel.  The actual model is the
    * passed-in ApplicationModel.
    */
    public final class TimeZoneListSelectionModel
        extends DefaultListSelectionModel
        implements ApplicationModelSelectionListener
    {
        private final ApplicationModel appMdl;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private TimeZoneListSelectionModel(ApplicationModel appMdl)
        {
            setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            this.appMdl = appMdl;
            appMdl.addSelectionListener(this);
        }

        // Requests to ListSelectionModel to modify the selection are passed
        // to the appMdl
        @Override
        public void clearSelection()
        {
            appMdl.setModelSelection(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
        {
            int modelIdx = tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(index0);
            String value = appMdl.getData()[modelIdx];
            appMdl.setModelSelection(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
        {
            int modelIdx = tbl.convertRowIndexToModel(index0);
            String value = appMdl.getData()[modelIdx];
            appMdl.setModelSelection(value);
        }

        // Notification from the app model about selection change gets
        // percolated back to the user interface
        @Override
        public void modelSelectionChanged(String selection, int selectedModelIndex)
        {
            if (selectedModelIndex == -1)
            {
                super.clearSelection();
                return;
            }
            int viewIndex = tbl.convertRowIndexToView(selectedModelIndex);
            if (viewIndex == -1)
                super.clearSelection();
            else
                super.setSelectionInterval(viewIndex, viewIndex);
        }
    }

    public static final class TimeZoneTableModel
        extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final String[] data;

        public TimeZoneTableModel(String[] data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override public int getRowCount() { return data.length; }

        @Override public int getColumnCount() { return 1; }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            if (columnIndex == 0)
                return data[rowIndex];
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("columnIndex="+columnIndex+" should be < 1");
        }

        @Override public String getColumnName(int column)
        { return "Time Zone"; }
    }

    private static final class StringRowFilter
        extends RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>
    {
        private String prefix;
        public void setPrefix(String value) { prefix = value; rowSorter.sort(); }

        private final TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter;

        public StringRowFilter(TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter)
        {
            this.rowSorter = rowSorter;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean include(
            Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry)
        {
            if (prefix == null)
                return true;
            String lowerCase = entry.getStringValue(0).toLowerCase();
            return lowerCase.startsWith(prefix);
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationModel appMdl = new ApplicationModel();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TableProblem(appMdl).setVisible(true));
    }

    private final JTable tbl;

    public TableProblem(ApplicationModel appMdl)
    {
        super("View-ModelView-Model Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TimeZoneTableModel mdl = new TimeZoneTableModel(appMdl.getData());

        tbl = new JTable(mdl);
        tbl.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        TimeZoneListSelectionModel tzListSelectionModel = new TimeZoneListSelectionModel(appMdl);
        tbl.setSelectionModel(tzListSelectionModel);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = (TableRowSorter<TableModel>)tbl.getRowSorter();
        StringRowFilter filter = new StringRowFilter(rowSorter);
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(filter);

        Box filterButtons = createFilterButtons(filter);

        Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        vbox.add(filterButtons);
        vbox.add(new JScrollPane(tbl));

        JLabel mdlSelect = new JLabel("App Model selection: ");
        appMdl.addSelectionListener((selection, selectedModelIndex) ->
            mdlSelect.setText("App Model selection: " + selection + " (" +
                selectedModelIndex + ")"));
        vbox.add(mdlSelect);

        add(vbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    private static Box createFilterButtons(StringRowFilter filter)
    {
        Box filterButtons = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        filterButtons.add(new JLabel("Filter: "));
        for (String filterStr : "All,Africa,America,Antarctica,Asia,Australia,Canada,Europe,Pacific,Us".split(","))
            addFilterButton(filter, filterButtons, filterStr);
        return filterButtons;
    }

    private static void addFilterButton(StringRowFilter filter,
        Box filterButtons, String buttonName)
    {
        String filterPrefix = "All".equals(buttonName) ? null : buttonName.toLowerCase();
        JButton asiaButton = new JButton(buttonName);
        asiaButton.addActionListener(ae -> filter.setPrefix(filterPrefix));
        filterButtons.add(asiaButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SCCE has way too many static classes.

Comment: I can see that. What would have been a preferred alternative? I'm not sure if anonymous inner classes would have been any better for understandability, nor separating the static inner classes as separate files. If you prefer separate files, feel free to use Refactor -> Move Type To New File in your IDE on each inner class. Other than that, I couldn't think of a way of making it any more concise while still clearly demonstrating the problem since it deals with the interaction of many elements.

Comment: "What would have been a preferred alternative?"  Classes and methods that don't have the keyword static.

Comment: I copied your code into my IDE.  I see a time zone JTable that seems to filter correctly.  I see a JLabel at the bottom right that shows what time zone I selected.  What am I supposed to see?  What sequence of actions will demonstrate the problem you have? Oh, as an aside, formatting your code using the Eclipse standard shaved your code length by 10%.

Comment: Because you're creating a GUI, I'd have suggested using the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  The model consists of plain Java getter / setter classes.  The view consists of classes that **use** Swing components.  The controller consists of Swing ActionListener and other listener classes.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc `The model consists of plain Java getter / setter classes`. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller): *The (model) central component of the pattern. It is the application's dynamic data structure, independent of the user interface.[5] It directly manages the **data, logic and rules** of the application*.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc From [GUI Architectures](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) : *In MVC, the **domain element is referred to as the model**. Model objects are completely ignorant of the UI.*

Comment: "What am I supposed to see?" - I have added a line to the first paragraph. "using the Eclipse standard shaved your code length by 10%" - I'm glad you were able to make it more readable for you. MVC vs M-VM-V: This is an interesting discussion, but I believe the stated problem would live through a redesign because the problem behavior is in the `JTable` and related classes, not in the architecture.

Comment: [please to check if this one fits with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854854/jtable-rowfilter-and-rowfilter-entry), something close/similair must be solved here by using JSpinner

Comment: to use hardcoded value for tersting purposes in defaultTableModel to avoids ...

Comment: @mKorbel, I checked out the example.  (Side note: Neat, I never knew about `RowFilter.andFilter()`!)  Your problem there dealt with the filtering conditions inside of the `RowFilter`. My problem deals with the side-effects of changing the `RowFilter` on the `SelectionModel`, so it doesn't quite apply.  Above you mentioned a `JSpinner` - I didn't see it in the link.  Maybe you meant to paste in a different link?

Answer (score 0):

A disappointing and unsatisfying solution to this problem is upon requesting a change of the filter value, before telling the `JTable`'s `RowSorter`, clear out the currently selected item in the model.

This is a change in the behavior, where the selection gets cleared, but prevents spurious clearing and resetting of the value when clicking through the filter values.

The change to the example code would involve passing the selection model to the action of the filter button.  The three methods that would change are below.

```
public TableProblem(ApplicationModel appMdl)
{
    super("View-ModelView-Model Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    TimeZoneTableModel mdl = new TimeZoneTableModel(appMdl.getData());

    tbl = new JTable(mdl);
    tbl.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    TimeZoneListSelectionModel tzListSelectionModel = new TimeZoneListSelectionModel(appMdl);
    tbl.setSelectionModel(tzListSelectionModel);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = (TableRowSorter<TableModel>)tbl.getRowSorter();
    StringRowFilter filter = new StringRowFilter(rowSorter);
    rowSorter.setRowFilter(filter);

    Box filterButtons = createFilterButtons(filter, tzListSelectionModel);

    Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    vbox.add(filterButtons);
    vbox.add(new JScrollPane(tbl));

    JLabel mdlSelect = new JLabel("App Model selection: ");
    appMdl.addSelectionListener((selection, selectedModelIndex) ->
        mdlSelect.setText("App Model selection: " + selection + " (" +
            selectedModelIndex + ")"));
    vbox.add(mdlSelect);

    add(vbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}

private static Box createFilterButtons(StringRowFilter filter,
    TimeZoneListSelectionModel tzListSelectionModel)
{
    Box filterButtons = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    filterButtons.add(new JLabel("Filter: "));
    for (String filterStr : "All,Africa,America,Antarctica,Asia,Australia,Canada,Europe,Pacific,Us".split(","))
        addFilterButton(filter, filterButtons, filterStr, tzListSelectionModel);
    return filterButtons;
}

private static void addFilterButton(StringRowFilter filter,
    Box filterButtons, String buttonName,
    TableProblem.TimeZoneListSelectionModel tzListSelectionModel)
{
    String filterPrefix = "All".equals(buttonName) ? null : buttonName.toLowerCase();
    JButton asiaButton = new JButton(buttonName);
    asiaButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
        tzListSelectionModel.clearSelection();
        filter.setPrefix(filterPrefix);
    });
    filterButtons.add(asiaButton);
}
```

Notice I will not be marking this Answer as the solution because it is more of a workaround, and an actual solution to the problem is preferred.